# remove spacing between custom cells in grouped style of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my application, I am using custom table cells to populate UITableView (grouped). The tableView has only one section, and this section has 4 rows. however, I see an unwanted gap between the rows. How to remove this gap?

I am using a background view for the tableView:

In `viewdidLoad`, i have done

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluegrad.png"]];
self.customerCareTableView.backgroundView = imageView1;
```

And what i am getting is:
[image]

this is what i want
[image]

Comment: May be you set your tableview separatorStyle none ?? then please remove it.

Comment: yes. i have set it to none. but even after setting it to single line, i am not getting the desired look.

Comment: Your custom cell height and the delegate returns the same height    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return desiredHeight;
}

Comment: yes.. they return the same height..

Comment: Have you tried this...                                self.customerCareTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
self.customerCareTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: Other wise you can use normaltable view instead of groupedone and set corner radius for your table view...

Comment: My suggestion is you can set the background image for your view not for table. And in the normal table view instead of grouped one you can set the background color as white and increase the separator width and separator color as clear color and set rounded corner for your table view....

Answer (score 0):

- First suggestion for this cases (even though you already tried this) is checking that the `separatorStyle` property of your tableview is correctly settled to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` for not having a 
  separator at all.
- When using custom assets as background images, be sure to have the image resource sliced correctly. There shouldn't be any extra pixels neither in the bottom nor top of those assets. You can check this using another app like Preview.
- Double check that you are setting the proper height of your cell, must be the same height of your background image. You should check that on the following method, (also you may want to check if there is any kind of constraint that may be causing a resize of your image at runtime

  `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Hope this helps!